# How to make a function to determine if something is a built in command for the shell I'm writing

Tags: c

I am wrting a shell.  I need a function to determine if the command entered in the shell by 
the user is a valid builtin command. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
    int is_builtin(command_t* command) {
    // TODO: Iterate through `valid_builtin_commands`
    while (valid_builtin_commands[i] != NULL )
    i++
    if(valid_builtin_commands[i] == command){
        return true
        }
    return -1;
}
```

im trying to accomplish more along these lines in limited in the libraries i can use.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking. No notion of what is a built-in command or what `command_t` is, also you have not tried to do anything.

Comment: you're going to need to come up with a list of builtin commands

Comment: Most likely, you will have a table of shell built-in commands for the shell you are presumably writing, and that table will include the command name.  You can write code to search that table (probably after using `qsort()` to sort it and using `bsearch()` to search it) for the name that was supplied.

Comment: It's your shell; the only person who can possibly know this answer is you. Unless someone else has handed you detailed requirements and they are not clear. In that case, only that someone else can help; it's not any clearer to any third party.

Answer (score -1):

I have a magic crystal ball which says:

```
int is_builtin(command_t* command) {
    return (command->flags & CMD_BUILT_IN) != 0;
}
```

Try that! You might have to define `flags` in the `command_t` structure, and populate that at the time the `command_t` object is instantiated from parsing the command input. Also, to supply the `CMD_BUILT_IN` constant in some header file somewhere.